# Verify Client Side Express Checkout from Server

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented client side checkout as demo'd here https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client. Its working fine while testing with sandbox account. But I am concerned about how we can verify whether the payment has actually gone through from the server side?
For eg: if the user executed a payment for Order number 'X', I want to make sure that the payment has been successful. I noteiced the transaction Id which I understand is generated by paypal only if the payment has gone through and we can recieve that Id in the parameter for payment execute call back:

```
actions.payment.execute().then(function (payment) { // where payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id is some value say 'xxx' });
```

The same Unique Id can be seen in the sandbox transaction details page (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_history-details-from-hub&id=xxx) as Unique Transaction IDxxx. Is there a way (a paypal endpoint) to verify this through a server side call? That is verfiy that the Transaction Id received at the server is a valid one from paypal.

Excuse my ignorance, are webhook events meant to do this?

Comment: Found that it is very much possible. We could get the sale's detail as shown here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#sale_get which has the status of the sale/transaction. We will need to have an oauth token from paypal for making the above request which is shown here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#make-your-first-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Get an access token

First we need to have an oAuth token from paypal. For this we need to do a POST to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token (sandbox url) passing our PayPal app's client Id and Secret. 
Details of the HttpClient object I used in C#:

- DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept: application/json
- DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage: en_US
- DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization: AuthenticationHeaderValue of Basic scheme, parameter of Base64String of bytes encoded from (clientId:clientSecret).

The response will have the property access_token which has the access token we want to pass in the next request to get the status of the transaction. For more details on getting access token refer: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token.

#### Get sale details

Now to make the request for sale/transaction details as said here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#sale_get.
Do a GET passing the access token as Bearer token in the Authorization header. 
And the unique transaction Id as parameter for the sale id. The response will have the property "state". Having the value "COMPLETED" ensures the transaction has gone successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IPN/Webhooks, then PayPal will send a notification to you for every payment with the transaction id, payment details. You can use that information for verifying the payment.

Comment: Was thinking how reliable it would be. If something has gone weird when the event fired. Would have been good if there is a paypal api/endpoint where we could validate it